# Dynamics 365 V9.0 detail(child) entity target doesnt contain parent entity reference when creating using entity.RelatedEntities

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'm work on Dynamics 365 online V9. I have encounted a problem when creating a new entity with related entity.

I have custom entities new_quote and new_quotedetail, with 1-N Relationship. I have a plugin on entity new_quotedetail on preCreate event that will check if the target contains the key "new_quoteid", otherwise il will block the creation.
the problem is that I want to create new_quote with its all details in the same time, so I use entity.RelatedEntities to create them. but it look like the child detail entity target doesn't contain the new_quoteid, is it normal?

I have tried to register the plugin in post-create event but still have the problem

Thanks
Song

Comment: what do you mean by create new_quote with its all details in the same time. Will you not have new_quote already created and once this record is created you will go ahead with creating child record (new_quotedetail) record.?

Comment: Hi, I have uesed the method mentioned in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/entity-operations-create, at "Create related entities in one operation"

Comment: Ok but in you case, you also have restriction on create of new_quotedetail entity and during create related entities, new_quote is not yet created in database. I would suggest try seperating logic for create of new_quote and then after this is created, try creating new_quotedetai. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Hi, yes. finally I have to create them seperatelly. thank u

Comment: I willl add this as answer, please mark it as solved. It will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Field is populated by associate message, if you are using the create related in one operation having logic to check on related entity create message wont work because like you say field not populated at that time. Move child record creation into second message and your plugin should work as is.

Comment: Hi, does that mean internally, the system create them and then associate the detail entities to the primary entity? OK, i have no other choice.  thank you

Comment: Yes Youre welcome.Would you kindly mark as solution if this resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this at one go.
Reason been your child entity has plugin on create which checks and restrict creation unless you have primary entity created.
I will suggest separate logic in 2 calls I.e first create parent entity and after create of parent then fire plugin to create child entity.